# httpOnly cookie when developing/debugging locally

Tags: .net, web-services, authentication, cookies, localhost

I have a web client and several web services (along with an auth service). I run the web on `web-test.domain.com` and the services on `services-test.domain.com`.

For debugging I run *some* of the web services locally. But the problem is when I run the auth service locally *(where the cookie is set)* but the others on `services-test.domain.com`, the cookie (with the sessionID) is not sent with the requests to the other web services (because its Domain is `localhost` and they're not running locally), so they always throw a `401 Unauthorized` exception and I'm automatically logged out from the web.

This is because the auth service is running on localhost so the response is a cookie with `Domain=localhost` but when the request is sent to the other web services, no cookie is sent because it's an httpOnly localhost cookie. Resulting in the other web services thinking that I'm not logged in.

Is there any way I can run the auth service locally and get a httpOnly cookie that works cross-domain (for localhost and services-test.domain.com)

How are you doing this when working with httpOnly domain-specific cookies, when developing, debugging and running the auth service locally, that sets the cookie?

Here's an image demonstrating the problem:

[image]

Possible solutions:

1. Run all of the web services locally.
2. Go to `web-test.domain.com`, log in and get the cookie for that domain (session A). Then log in on the local running service and get a cookie for localhost (session B). Then session A will be used for all external services and session B will be used for all local services.
3. Add `services-test.domain.com` to `/etc/hosts` file so the cookie is set for that domain and works on external services too.

*Edit:* What I'm doing currently is using #2. But it doesn't make fully sense to me, because there are two different sessions.

Answer (score 0):

As specified on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials

> XMLHttpRequest responses from a different domain cannot set cookie
> values for their own domain unless...

You can overcome this issue by adding some flags so that you allow setting the cookie on a different domain.
All your `XMLHttpRequest` requests need to be made with the following flag: `withCredentials: true`

Also, you backend server needs to respond with a special header (`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`) to allow sending cookies on cross origin requests.

---

Make sure you do these only in debug mode. You need to add `withCredentials:true` if your application is in dev mode, also you can run a script to add `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to your backend web server (eg. nginx or add a config to your API)

Note that CORS wildcard (*) won't work if you add `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` and you will need to specify the host, methods and headers explicitly.